# Set of all real numbers with the Scott topology

Tags: general-topology

It is known that a space $X$ is compact iff every net in $X$ has a cluster point.

Let $\sum\mathbb{R}$ be set of all real numbers with the Scott topology. I know that $\sum\mathbb{R}$ is not compact. Because $\{(a,+\infty): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is an open covering of $\mathbb{R}$ but it does not have a finite subcover.

But I failed to understand why $\sum\mathbb{R}$ is not compact using above property.
I think that for any net $\{x_n\}\in \sum\mathbb{R}$, 0 is cluster point. Because for every open neighborhood $U$ of 0, and every $m$, we can find $n\geq m$ (such that $x_n\geq 0$) then $x_n\in U$.

I feel that there is something wrong in my proof but I do not know which part. Please explain to me in which part my prove is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\langle -n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no cluster point: for any $x\in\Bbb R$, the open set $(x-1,\to)$ is a nbhd of $x$ that contains only finitely many terms of the sequence.